# Dialogflow ES curl to specific custom environments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have Dialogflow ES angent with a version.
With "Draft" version in Dialogflow, I can call curl command and get response like below.

```
curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"  \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"  \
-d "{\"queryInput\":{\"text\":{\"text\":\"バージョン\",\"languageCode\":\"ja\"}},\"queryParams\":{\"source\":\"DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE\",\"timeZone\":\"Asia/Tokyo\",\"sentimentAnalysisRequestConfig\":{\"analyzeQueryTextSentiment\":true}}}" \
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<project_name>/agent/sessions/<session_id>:detectIntent"
```

When I tried to access custom version, I got 404 in response text like below.

```
curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"  \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"  \
-d "{\"queryInput\":{\"text\":{\"text\":\"バージョン\",\"languageCode\":\"ja\"}},\"queryParams\":{\"source\":\"DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE\",\"timeZone\":\"Asia/Tokyo\",\"sentimentAnalysisRequestConfig\":{\"analyzeQueryTextSentiment\":true}}}" \
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<project_name>/agent/environments/DEV/sessions/<session_id>:detectIntent"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v2/projects/%3Cproject_name%3E/agent/environments/DEV/sessions/%3Csession_id%3E:detectIntent</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I followed the guid in [Dialogflow ES Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-versions#test_your_agent_in_an_environment).

I made the active environments Dialogflow console.

[image: Environments tab]

[image: The active status]

Does anybody know how to curl to custome environment?

Comment: Could you try curling `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my-project-id/agent/environments/development/users/-/sessions/123456789:detectIntent` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing your agent in a custom environment alter the endpoint URL to

`https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my-project-id/agent/environments/<env-name>/users/-/sessions/123456789:detectIntent`

curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "x-goog-user-project: PROJECT_ID" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @request.json \
    "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my-project-id/agent/environments/<env-name>/users/-/sessions/123456789:detectIntent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [@SakshiGat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15750473/sakshi-gatyan) mentioned, the curl URL was invalid.

Invalid URL:
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<project_name>/agent/environments/DEV/sessions/<session_id>:detectIntent"

Valid URL:
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/**<project_id>**/agent/environments/DEV/**users/-**/sessions/<session_id>:detectIntent"